# Overlay items in qtgraphicsscene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qt4.8

I would like to draw some dynamical overlay elements in a scene.

Usually I would go for the paintEvent in the view or foreground painting for doing overlays, but this time I need to interact with these elements: they are like every other item in the scene... Mostly, this choice comes from the fact that these items are somewhat complex, and they share the rendering with other QGraphicsItem(s).

The problem is that, being overlayed, they shall be treated a bit differently than any other element in the scene: rendered in *view* coord space, not in scene coord space, and ignore changes in the view rect, dragging, dropping, rubber band selection, and such.

The question is somewhat general: how could I use the scene for a thing like this? Is there a better option for doing overlays e.g. using multiple scenes and rendering them all, in some magic way, in a single view widget?

Comment: never found how to do this properly, I hope someone can answer

Comment: What do you think about subclassing QGraphicsScene to treat separately the items?

Comment: could you develop on the subject please ?

Comment: Sure, the idea is to subclass QGraphicsScene to provide a different interface to handle different items. All items are still in the scene and are rendered as usual by the view, but user of the scene has "overlay items" and "standard items". The subclassed scene shall internally handle the overlay items positioning, and possibly also a separate set of events for the overlays. Do you think this could work and be convenient?